# Cordova camera take picture as Blob object

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to take a picture using `cordova-plugin-camera`. I'd like the result to be a `File` or `Blob` object.

However, the [`destinationType`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/index.html#module_Camera.DestinationType) must be one of `DATA_URL` or `FILE_URI`.

The docs state:

> DATAURL can be very memory intensive and cause app crashes or out of memory errors. Use FILEURI or NATIVE_URI if possible

However, as far as I can tell, converting such a file uri to a Blob takes these steps:

1. Rendering the uri on a `<img/`
2. Draw image on a canvas
3. Read canvas as base64
4. Convert base64 to `Blob`

I find it hard to believe that this is more efficient than using `DATAURL`. So I might just as well use `DATAURL` for this and skip steps 1-3.

Is there a way to just get a picture taken as a `Blob` object in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't extract a `BLOB` from the Cordova camera plugin.

The way to get a `BLOB` is to convert your base64 encoded string to a `BLOB` and use that.

Here's a method (ES6 compliant) that allows you to convert to `BLOB` and just the **sliceSize** to be more memory efficient.

```
/**
 * Turn base 64 image into a blob, so we can send it using multipart/form-data posts
 * @param b64Data
 * @param contentType
 * @param sliceSize
 * @return {Blob}
 */
private getBlob(b64Data:string, contentType:string, sliceSize:number= 512) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

    let byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    let byteArrays = [];

    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
        let slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

        let byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        let byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    let blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
    return blob;
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is the `sliceSize` for?